# calling javascript from update panel doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I have the following update panel tag:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" onload="load()">
```

in my header I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        function load() {
            doSomething....
        }
</script>
```

When I run this I get:
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.aform_webform2_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'load' and no extension method 'load' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.aform_webform2_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone help me figure out how to call that function whenever my update panel loads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `onload` property on the update panel. You should remove it. You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.vikramlakhotia.com/Run_a_JavaScript_function_after_every_or_specific_callback.aspx). You could use:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(load);
```

and the `load()` will be triggered after every update panel update. But if you want to target a specific update panel you could use the following in the code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "foo", "load();", true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much and I'm sorry I asked an already answered question, I really did research this, I guess I just wasn't looking in the right places :-/

Answer (score 2):

there is a function also can do

```
function pageLoad()
{
// do some thing after each partial post back happen
}
```

Regards